# PHP implement preg_match with an array then preg_replace the matches

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match

I grabbed this very useful snippet from php.net and modified it.

```
$cat = strip_tags(trim($_POST["cat"]));
$joke = strip_tags(trim($_POST["joke"]));
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'bear';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[2] = 'slow';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $joke);
```

This code works perfectly. Any time any of the words in the $patterns array are present they are replaced with the corresponding $replacement.

I'd like to run a preg_match on $patterns first and if there is a match set a variable named $status to true and run the preg_replace. But if there is not a preg_match I'd like to have an else if that says else if no match set $status to false.

Is it even possible to run preg_match on my $patterns array how I have it set up now? If so how could I do that? I'd like to run preg_match on the existing array to reduce writing more code for a second array that would just contain the same words.

Comment: `$cat` is declared, but never accessed.  We do not have a [mcve].  This question needs to be [edit]ed so that solutions can be confidently provided.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
$joke2 = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $joke);
$status = ($joke == $joke2) ? 'green' : 'red';
```

Option 2:

```
$matches = array_filter($patterns, function($a) use($joke) { return preg_match($a, $joke); });
if (!empty($matches)) {
    $status = 'red';
    $joke2 = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $joke);
} else {
    $status = 'green';
}
```

What you are asking is option 2 but imho it's too complicated

Comment: How would you do it then? I need to check for the words, and if they are present replace them and set a variable to let me know words were replaced. If there were no matches then nothing needed replaced and I need to know that down the line as well.